# ISNULL with SUM with Cast on the same column

Tags: sql-server

I try to sum and cast a column name, like this:

```
ISNULL(SUM(CAST( VPL.Amount AS VARCHAR(10))), '')  as total
```

but I get this error:

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

thank you

Comment: The error is clear, you can only `SUM` numeric values

Comment: Just *don't* cast to text before summing - ie reverse the order of SUM(CAST` to `CAST(SUM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the `SUM` part first and then cast the result.

```
ISNULL(CAST(SUM([VPL].[Amount]) AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS [total]
```

Comment: Thank you. But then I get this error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: That would be the same error you stated in your original question. Are you sure you used the code provided in the answer? Works for me and really should not raise the error.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` can be used with `NUMERIC` columns only. `NULL` values are ignored.

```
CAST(SUM(VPL.Id) AS VARCHAR(10)) as total
```

Comment: Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Use the column datatype in the query like DECIMAL/ int which is mentioned for the column "VPL.Amount"

```
ISNULL(SUm(CAST( VPL.Amount AS DECIMAL)), '')  as total
```

Comment: Thank you for reply